# How do I loop in PHP and get multiple rows returned from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have made a log in system which asks for email activation. It all works fine. However, there is no real 'spam' protection. When the user creates an account, it inserts a row with the column 'activated' = 'NO'.

I want to make it so that if the user hasn't activated their account with, let's say, 3 hours, it will delete the row from the MySQL database. I have made a cron job which runs the following every 30 mins.

```
<?php

ob_start();
include 'global.php';
ob_end_clean();

$check_times = (time() - ('-3 hours'));
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE time<=$check_times and activated='NO'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$inactive_user = $row['username'];

echo $inactive_user;
echo "<br>";
echo $check_times;
?>
```

The 'global.php' is connecting to the database. The above code works but only for one row (IT ONLY RETURNS THE VALUE OF THE FIRST INSTANCE IT COMES ACROSS)

I have looked into 'Do While' and 'Loop Until' and whatever but don't know what to put in the brackets...Do While (//what do I put in here?)

At the moment, the code only echos out the instances but I will change that to delete

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137992/how-do-i-loop-through-a-mysql-query-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert all the `usernames` inside `$inactive_user[]`.

```
    $inactive_user = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result){
    $inactive_user[] = $rows['username'];
}
```

And then loop the array and echo every user:

```
foreach($inactive_user as $us){
    echo $us;
}
```

As `mysql` is deprecated, you should use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: Brilliant, works a treat. However, it doesn't seem to like mysqli. Is there a reason for this and how important is it?

Comment: Sorry...brain freeze. How exactly would I delete them from the table?    I was thinking something like:         foreach($inactive_user as $us){
    mysql_query ("DELETE * FROM users WHERE username = $inactive_user ");
}

Comment: $us is one string and it wouldn't recognise them as different users and $inactive user doesn't work

Comment: mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE username = '$us'").
Note that you need to set in your `TABLE users` an `UNIQUE INDEX` to avoid duplicated `usernames`.
`mysql` will not be supported in the future. `mysqli` is the "new updated" `mysql`. If you want to query with `mysqli` you have to set your connection with `mysqli`. E.g. `$link = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);` http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

If my post answered your question, please accept it by click on the check.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $inactive_user = $row['username'];
}
```

Additionally, you should phase out the use of `mysql_` functions, and look into `mysqli` as a replacement - `mysql_` is deprecated.

Comment: I get a lot of errors for line 9 - $result = mysqli_query($query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error().$query);

Comment: I can't write all the errors but it's expecting at least 2 parameters on line 9 and I get this 'Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given'

Comment: It's not a swapout of functions - there's a bit more to the transition but you absolutely should look into it - [perhaps start here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi).